# Debug Mapstruct implementations with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mapstruct

I'm using MapStruct 1.3.0.Final to convert Dtos into POJOs and vice versa with the **spring** value into *mapstruct.defaultComponentModel* option.

Is there a way to debug generated implementations (by default in the folder `target/generated-sources`) of the mappers using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

If your Eclipse is properly configured then the `target/generated-sources` folder should be part of the Java sources and you would be able to debug and use those classes as if they were under `src/main/java`

Comment: It was the first thing I did (and currently the project has that configuration), however when I try to debug that part of the code, it never reaches the code of the converter implementation, always "ends" in the `AopUtils` (an internal Spring class)